# Prevent user from vertical recording

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using an imagePicker to allow users to record videos and take photos.
I have no problem in retrieving everything and all ... However I'm asked to prevent users from filming vertically. 
Ideally, an alert would be displayed and would not be dismissed as long as the user doesn't orient his/her phone accordingly (landscape left/landscape right).
Moreover, this alert mustn't be presented when the user is in photo mode. Only video mode. 
I'm fairly certain that it isn't possible but I'm posting this here, just in case ... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? Why restrict the user at all? It is their phone, it’s their video, why put any obstacles in the way of the user using your app? I completely agree with your dislike of vertical videos... but I disagree that this is a nice UX.

Comment: If you’re using a UIImagePickerController then I presume an option is to select a previously recorded video? Are you going to also restrict those so that only horizontal videos can be selected?

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm merely asked to do it. I couldn't care less about what is done. UIImagePicker also allows video capture. I want to prevent even the capture.

Comment: Fair enough. With UIImagePicker I’m not sure. You could perhaps look into creating a custom overlay for it which is something you can do. Other than that I’d go for creating my own recorder. But that would be a lot of work.

Comment: Your best bet will be to let them finish recording and check the orientation afterwards. If anything else, you can have the UIImagePicker's parent detect the device's orientation and present a view over the image picker whenever it is either portrait or portrait/upsidedown